# Add price data from a table in html, please not in javascript document

Tags: html

hello can you help me to be able to add the prices of the products that will be in the shopping cart, I need to do the work in html or python with flask sqlalchemy and not in a javascript document

> 

```
            <table  id="mytable" class="product">
                
                
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                    <th>Product</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                    <th>Total</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan=2>Total</td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
                <tbody>
                    {% for product in products %}
                    <tr>
                        <td id ='products'>{{product.food}}</td>
                        <td>&dollar;{{product.price}}</td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Example of table in database:

```
 id |          food          | price
----+--------------------------+--------
1 | Pizza Mozarella Familiar |   31.9
2 | Pizza Pepperoni Familiar |   21.9
3 | Pizza Mozarella presonal |   10.0
```

Comment: Based on the Liquid template syntax, it looks like you're looping over a `products` data set to render HTML. Not knowing what the data looks like, where they come from, and how they're handled in which language, it's not possible to answer.

Comment: @BumhanYu I just put how the table data looks like

Comment: So, you have `products` in an array. You loop over them with `for product in products` method and render `product.food` and `product.price` in each table. Now you want to go through the `products` again, and calculate the total value of `product.price` and render the single value. I don't know whether you can pull the value directly from Liquid variable somewhere or you'd need to do a custom calculation.